# NGINX UI is shown in all addresses

Tags: user-interface, nginx

I have an NGINX which shows an html file as the UI on localhost with the following config:

```
upstream api {
      server api:8020;
    }

    server {
        client_max_body_size 500M;
        proxy_connect_timeout   600;
        proxy_send_timeout      600;
        proxy_read_timeout      600;
        send_timeout            600;
        client_body_timeout     600;
        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/json;

        # backend urls
        location /extract_text {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://api;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

        # static files
        location /static {
            proxy_pass http://api;
        }

        # frontend
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        }
```

The issue is about showing html UI in all addresses like: localhost/1, localhost/john, etc. which I didn't define. I want to have other api with different addresses like localhost/italy but I don't want to see the NGINX html.

Comment: It is the last part of your `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` directives makes internal rerwite to `/index.html` in case when no existing static file/directory is found according to the given request URI. The default behavior is `try_files $uri $uri/ =404`, unless explicitly specified something else, so you can simply remove that `try_files` directive (and even the whole `location / { ... }` block).

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I removed the whole location / { ... }.
I noticed that I need to add  location /defined {... } if I need to add new apis in my fastapi backend.

Comment: Well, you can proxy any request at all using `location / { proxy_pass http://api; }` leaving decision what to do with that request to your `api` backend.